# set persistent search bar

Tags: nexus-7, 5.0-lollipop, google-search

On my Nexus 5 I have a persistent search bar that appears on all screens, regardless of launcher. I cannot remember or find where and how I set this.  I would like to set the same feature on my Nexus 7.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Some launchers (e.g. Nova) provide a way to show / hide the persistent search bar. So, it's not just "regardless of launcher". Could you specify if you are using the stock launcher or a custom launcher right now? If custom, which one?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  On my Nexus 5 the persistent search bar persists with Nova launcher, which is what I use,  and also with the Google Now launcher.  Not, however, with Go Ex. I can't remember what I did to get it on the phone, but I'm using Nova,  also on the Nexus 7,  and it's not there and I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment that the persistent search bar is not available on GO launcher makes your initial "regardless of launcher" comment invalid.

It is highly likely that GO Ex does not have an option to show the persistent search bar, as observed in [a forum post](http://androidforums.com/threads/persistent-search-bar.555869/). You might want to revert to using Nova (which I personally use) or Apex.

UPDATE 2014-01-27 17:10 For Nova launcher, you can configure the persistent search bar here:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right about my error, of course, thanks for pointing that out.  But to clarify, my issue still is: I have the persistent search bar on my Nexus 5 with Nova, which I use and prefer.  I would like to have the same feature on my Nexus 7, also using Nova.  How do I set that up?

Comment: @SteveBaker BTW, you may want to accept the Answer if you think this solved your problem. :)

Comment: Not quite, yet.  My problem remains:how to  set up the persistent search bar with Nova on a nexus 7? Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Comment: @SteveBaker Have you seen the settings I put in the screenshots?

Comment: Just saw them.  Thanks very much.  Got it now.  I appreciate your patience.